# Removing white spaces between facets when using ggplotly()

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, ggplotly

I wish to make a ggplot object interactive using plotly. When I use `ggplotly()`, huge white spaces are introduced between my facets, making the plot small and weird looking:

[image: plotly facets]

Compared to how big and neat it looks when using `ggplot` only:

[image: ggplot object]

My reproducible code is:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

p <- ggplot(tips, aes(x=total_bill, y=tip/total_bill)) + 
  geom_point(shape=1) + 
  facet_wrap( ~ day, ncol=2)

ggplotly(p)
```

I don't know if its my computer settings or something is wrong with my code. Am using R version 4.0.2, ggplot2 version 3.3.2 and plotly version 4.9.2.1. Someone help me retain the size and add interactivity to my plot.

I have tried the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58263918/ggplotly-not-working-properly-when-number-are-facets-are-more) by Cam McMains but nothing changes.

#### **Update**

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

p <- ggplot(tips, aes(x=total_bill, y=tip/total_bill)) + 
  geom_point(shape=1) + 
  theme(panel.spacing=unit(0,'npc'))+
  facet_wrap( ~ day, ncol=2)
  
ggplotly(p)
```

Gives
[image: update]

Comment: So if you set `theme(panel.spacing=unit(0,'npc')` (or something otherwise very small), does that fix things in your `ggplotly()` plot?

Comment: @chemdork123 that collapses the horizontal plots together and reduces the distance between the vertical plots.  See update above.

Comment: Interesting.  I don't have your `tips` dataframe, but when I try using `mtcars`, I'm not getting the large vertical spacing you you.  Reprex: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~factor(carb))`.  Does that change anything for you?

Comment: @chemdork123 try maximizing your plot by zooming and see if the white spaces appear.

Comment: The spaces appear... but only slightly larger and nothing like in your example.  Scaling is similar to (but not exactly like) the same plot using `ggplot2` alone.

Comment: Try saving as an HTML widget: `library(htmlwidgets)`, then `saveWidget(ggplotly(p), 'test.html')` should do it.  When you open the resulting html in a browser, do you still see the same spacing?

Comment: @F.Mueni interesting. I ran your code and white spaces are just the same size as when using ggplot. I am on R 3.6.3, plotly 4.9.2.1. Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @johnjohn I haven't solved the problem yet, maybe this is happening because of my computer settings.